# How do the xConnect Docker containers correspond to the Azure xConnect app services?

Tags: xconnect, azure, docker, container

I've tried to find documentation on the various xConnect roles that exist and their names and map them to the names of the xConnect containers in an XP1 container setup and an Azure PaaS configuration, but I'm not confident that I've got the mapping right.

I reviewed [this documentation from Sitecore on the topic](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-and-the-xdb.html), but it contains yet a third convention of naming.

How do the following roles map up between the different infrastructure platforms?

## Docker containers

This list is taken from the [Sitecore **docker examples** repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/tree/develop/custom-images/docker/build)

1. cortexprocessing
2. cortexprocessingworker
3. cortexreporting
4. xdbautomation
5. xdbautomationrpt
6. xdbautomationworker
7. xdbcollection
8. xdbrefdata
9. xdbsearch
10. xdbsearchworker

## Azure PaaS

1. cortexprc
2. cortexrep
3. maops
4. marep
5. ops
6. xccollect
7. xcref
8. xcsearch

It looks like some of these are doubled up. Perhaps the workers are consolidated (e.g. cortexprocessing + cortexprocessingworker = cortexprc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### For Azure PaaS infrastructure:

Looking at the Azure AppServices packages for a scaled XP solution, you will find that that the following three workers are deployed in their correlated app services and they are configured to run as Azure WebJobs.

- **xConnect Search Indexer** - It runs as Azure WebJob in the xConnect Collection Search app service.
- **Marketing Automation Engine Worker** - It runs as Azure WebJob in the Marketing Automation Operations app service.
- **Cortex Processing Engine Worker** - It runs as Azure WebJob in the Cortex Processing app service.

You can explore the defined WebJobs of an app service in the Azure Portal, accessing the WebJobs section in the Settings area on the left navigation.

### For Kubernetes infrastructure:

Each worker service container runs in its own independent single-container pod in a Kubernetes cluster.

### Mapping of Docker Containers & Azure App Services:

The table below shows the potential mapping from a file system perspective of Docker containers and Azure App Services for a Sitecore XP scaled topology:

| Docker Container | Azure App Service |
| --- | --- |
| cortexprocessing cortexprocessingworker | cortexprc |
| cortexreporting | cortexrep |
| xdbautomation xdbautomationworker | maops |
| xdbautomationrpt | marep |
| xdbcollection | xccollect |
| xdbrefdata | xcref |
| xdbsearch xdbsearchworker | xcsearch |

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the detailed info and the great mapping table!